# How to add `<input>` elements with button click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### How to use ng-bind in realtime after appending an object

I want to be able to add a new element and use the ng-bind property to change the value of the new element.

I've tried multiple things, please see the code below for the best I've been able to come up with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#create-input").click(function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("p");
    var code = document.createElement("span");
    code.innerHTML = "{{input2}}";
    newInput.innerHTML = "<p>{input2}:&ensp;<input type='text' ng-model='name2'>&emsp; {{name2}}</p>";
    $("#target-container").append(newInput);
    $("#main-container").append(code);
  });
});
```

When I add text the newly appended input, the appended `{{name2}}` value does not change. I do not understand why I am unable to change `{{name2}}` via the text input box after appending.

Comment: It's because Angular doesn't work when the content is appended through other libraries and after the DOM has loaded. This is partly why it's not a good practice to use jQuery with Angular.

Comment: Got it. Would Regex be a better solution in your opinion or maybe just Vanilla JS?

Comment: No, if anything that would be worse. I'd suggest using Angular alone to update the content in the DOM.

Comment: Is there a good way to do that after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: you would need to call $compile on the newInput, from angularjs. Avoid to do that with thirdparty libraries, create directives/components it will be way more easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ng-repeat` directive to add input elements to the DOM:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.arr=[
       {name: "name1", value: ""}
    ];
    $scope.addInput = function() {
        $scope.arr.push( {
            name: "name" + ($scope.arr.length+1),
            value: ""
        })
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
    <div ng-repeat="elem in arr">
       {{elem.name}}: 
        <input ng-model="elem.value">        
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addInput()">Add Input</button>
    <div>{{arr}}</div>
</body>
```